# 6,000 years or 6,013 or 6,023?

Tags: messiah, ymoth-hamoshiach

I heard a lecture that the 6,000yr before the Messianic period begins is an approximation for the exact number of 6,013yr (or possibly 6,023yr as my memory may not be serving me right). I searched and tried to find a source for this awkward exact number but could not find it. I was wondering if anyone can provide the source and an additional source that explains the significance of the 13 or 23yr remainder. If someone can also show that the 6013/6023 is not an authentic opinion, that would be great too.

This is not a question on alternatives to the 6,000yr opinion (of which there are many). I believe this question is a clarification on the 6,000yr opinion.

Answer (score -1):

At 1st glance, it sounds like someone may have tried to make an analogy between the letters of the Torah and the 6000 years that this world will exist including the days of the Messiah.

A Torah actually contains 304,805 letters. But like is emphasized in kabbalistic and chassidic teachings, letters are defined in 2 ways.

Written letters are defined by positive space/boundary. Engraved letters are defined by negative space/boundary.

If one considers the analogy in the physical universe of matter (what we see and detect) and dark matter (the aspect of matter which we generally don't see or detect and which comprises according to current theories the majority of the universe), the idea isn't so difficult to comprehend. Dark matter would equate with the space around each letter in a Sefer Torah. For the Sefer Torah to be valid, each letter must have that clear space around it. When considering the entire klaf of the Sefer Torah (the surface of skin written upon which is also empty space) the dark matter is far greater than the matter (the ink).

So absolute letter definition has both definition aspects resulting in the concept that the Torah contains (approximately) 600,000 letters. Doubling 304,805 results in exactly 609,610 letters.

Dividing by 100 to draw the analogy to exact years results in 6,096 years that this world will last.

This would then alter the calculations of how long a day in terms of G-d's years from Chapter 90:4 of Tehillim results in.

> For in Your sight a thousand years are like yesterday that has passed, like a watch of the night.

The Messianic period begins before the end of the 6th day (actual Shabbat) following the halachic concept of when Shabbat should be brought in on Friday.

Doing the math, 6096 years divided by 6 days means a single day is 1,016 years exactly. Dividing by 24 hours in a day results in 42.333 years per halachic hour.

The earliest to take on Shabbat is Plag HaMinchah or 1.25 hours before actual night. 42.333 years times 1.25 results in 52.9 (53 years) before the 6,096 actual years that this world will exist, or the year 6,043 (which coincides to Plag HaMinchah of the sixth day) is the commencement of the Messianic period using that analogy with the actual number of letters of the Torah.

But just to emphasize, this is not the way this concept has been taught, neither by the Vilna Gaon, nor within the teachings of Chassidut.

The traditional teaching places Plag HaMinchah, meaning the beginning of the Messianic era, at the year 5750/51 or 1990/1991 on the secular calendar.

Comment: Some hold you can take on Shabbat 2 hours back into Friday so 6096-(42.333*2)=6011.33 which is closer to the OP's number.

Comment: @DoubleAA Valid point. You are considering the difference between Rabbeinu Tam and the Gaonim?

Comment: No, just generally skeptical of plag mincha being a meaningful time for anything besides the rabbinic border of afternoon prayers, a few inconclusive passing references in late rishonim notwithstanding.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Is the traditional teaching Chabad? It would be very convenient for them.

Comment: @N.T. This idea doesn't originate with Chabad. It's found in many places throughout the Torah (meaning including all of the Oral Torah). So in that sense, yes, of course it is the traditional teaching of Chabad. Lubavitchers accept the entire Torah, both written and oral.

Comment: I very much appreciate the calculations above. But do you have an authentic source for a count that is a bit greater than 6000yr (my original question)? I squarely remember seeing this somewhere.

Comment: I have never seen anything making that extension beyond the year 6000 for the beginning of the era of the Messiah.  Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato and others talk about the concept of what goes beyond the year 6000 including up to the 10th millennium. But your question is specifically dealing the beginning of the Messianic era. In context, it would be like saying it's OK to light candles for Shabbat after 3 stars on Friday night. Like I pointed out to DoubleAA, we are supposed to increase to the time we call Holy from the time we call Profane. That means sooner, not later.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Your answer seems to take a couple accepted ideas (space around the letters and a possuk in Tehillim) and make a bunch of leaps. Who connected the letters in Torah to the six thousand years? Who said you should divide by 100? And according to the traditional view, why should plag be 5750 when that is roughly equivalent to noon?

Comment: @N.T. The OP brought up that he recalls he has seen a source connecting the beginning of the era of the Messiah to 6013 or 6023. Like I said in my comment just preceding your last, I have never seen any source making such a statement. Every traditional source that I have seen discussing the subject puts it in the context of what is found in Shas & midrash about this world (including the era of the Messiah) lasting 6000 years which corresponds to the 6 days of creation. I explained how one could reason out the later date by relating it to the 600K letters of the Torah. Cont’d. next comment

Comment: @N.T. There are many sources for the concept that the written Torah is literally G-d’s will. So it isn’t a great leap to realize this includes the Era of the Messiah. The numerical divisions of ones, tens, hundreds, thousands and tens of thousands are discussed particularly in kabbalistic literature as relating to descent from one level of existence to another. Concerning the year 5750, you should look at the teaching of the Vilna Gaon in Sefer Kol HaTor among many others. The hours of night are not included in the calculation of plag HaMinchah.

Comment: Of course the era of the Messiah is in the Torah. But how do you know it corresponds to letters? And of course numbers have significance. But just choosing 100 seems random. And if you don't include night, you are still at around 3 pm.

Comment: @N.T. All aspects of what comprise the Torah for us ( including the aspect that it is made up of letters with specific requirements) implies that the Era of the Messiah is somehow contained within them. The dividing by 100 is only to connect the total number of letters in the written Torah (which also happens to correspond to the number of root souls of the Jewish people) to the number of years relating to the question from the OP. But it isn’t random. See prior comment about descent or ascent in levels of existence/worlds.

Comment: Not contradicting you, just what is your source for that?

Comment: @N.T. Traditional Jewish teaching is that the five books of Moshe, the written Sefer Torah, is literally G-d’s will. He is one. This is the miraculous thing about learning Torah, saying it thinking it, etc. This is brought in many places and discussed by many of the Sages at length. But the most elegant expression comes from the Zohar which simply states that the Holy One, blessed be He, the written Torah and Israel are all one.

Comment: That is a generality. Go back to the Messiah and letters being connected. Please also explain plag being 1991, which sounds really suspicious.

Comment: @N.T. You keep referring back to the letters and their association with the era of Moshiach. Do you understand what the OP was asking? He’s referencing this concept in association with slightly past the year 6000. I offered the illustration of how that calculation could comply with the teaching that the Torah contain 600K letters which also correspond to 600K root souls of the Jewish people. 600K divided by 100 gives the 6000 year relationship. It’s not random. It’s simply the math. That the divisor also happens to relate to a specific Torah concept of transition from world to world is a bonus

Comment: You said: "All aspects of what comprise the Torah for us ( including the aspect that it is made up of letters with specific requirements) implies that the Era of the Messiah is somehow contained within them." Please give a source for that. And plag being 1991.

Comment: @N.T. I have given you several sources. You aren’t going to them.